# What is the largest of the five missing numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

This is Q28 from Australian Maths Competition 2014.

A circle is surrounded by 6 other circles,in a hexagonal formation.The leftmost circle is 0,which the rightmost circle is 1000.Each of the five missing numbers is the average of its neighbours. What is the largest of the 5 missing numbers?

What I tried:

Let the numbers be $x,y,z,j,k$

The number in the centre=$x=\frac {1000+0+y+z+j+k}{6} -(1)$

$1000=\frac {j+x+y}{3} $

$0=\frac {z+x+k}{3}$

$1000=\frac {2(x+y+z+k+j)}{6}$ -(2)

Substituting (1) into (2),

$5x-2y-2z-2j-2k=0$

And I'm lost.I have seen this type of questions in competitions always.But I have always no clue.

Comment: What is the given number, $100$ or $1000$? Edit it.

Comment: and moreover, you said that only missing numbers are means of their neighbours, so the second and third expressions you wrote are wrong

Comment: Sorry,my mistake.It's $1000$

Comment: Wrong?Which paragraph?

Comment: This is most a problem of a linear system with five unknowns but not difficult to solve.

Comment: I couldn't see there was 5 equations to be formed...I though those that in algebraic values would be useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the numbers be arranged as follows:  $$\begin{array}{ccccc} & a & & b & \\ 0 & & c & & 1000 \\ & d & & e & \end{array}$$ Then we have the relationships $$\begin{align*} 3a &= b + c \\ 3d &= c + e \\ 3b &= a + c + 1000 \\ 3e &= c + d + 1000 \\ 6c &= a + b + d + e + 1000. \end{align*}$$  If we add up the first four equations, we obtain $$3(a+b+d+e) = 4c + (a+b+d+e) + 2000,$$ or $$2c = a+b+d+e - 1000.$$  Subtracting this result from the fifth equation yields $4c = 2000$, or $c = 500$.  Consequently, $$\begin{align*} 3a &= b + 500 \\ 3b &= a + 1500. \end{align*}$$  Their sum gives $2(a+b) = 2000$, or $a+b = 1000$, hence $3a - (1000 - a) = 500$, or $a = 375$, consequently $b = 625$.  Since the equations for $d$ and $e$ have the same form as those for $a$ and $b$, we also find $d = a = 375$ and $e = b = 625$.

---

It is not difficult to generalize this solution so that if in place of $0$ and $1000$ we write $x$ and $y$ respectively, then $$(a,b,c,d,e) = \left(\frac{5x+3y}{8}, \frac{3x+5y}{8}, \frac{x+y}{2}, \frac{5x+3y}{8}, \frac{3x+5y}{8}\right).$$

Comment: Sorry,my mistake it's $1000$ instead of $100$

Comment: Wait,so all I had to do was list out all the equations that could be formed...?

Comment: Shouldn't be divided by 6 or 3?Last paragraph feels weird to me.

Comment: @ArcNeoepi You are more than welcome to choose values for $x$ and $y$ (such as the originally specified $0$ and $1000$), substitute these into the last equation, and check that the result does indeed satisfy the conditions stated in the question.  Intuition is fallible.

Comment: Can the same method be applied if I have another set of circles surrounding the set of circles that are in hexagonal formation?